# How do hide line in jpgraph?

Tags: php, jpgraph

This is my LinePlot.

[image]

I want to hide the lines in plot. My plot just mark.

Like this image.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe a [Scatter Graph](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15s05.html) would be more appropriate?

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @showdev . The "SetCSIMTargets" can using scatter plot? I want to add the mouse hover in scatter plot. This is my reference link [barcsim_popup](http://www.asial.co.jp/jpgraph/demo/src/Examples/show-example.php?target=barcsim_popup.php) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to set hide line

$lineplot->SetWeight(0);